# Quiero retornar la suma de las cantidades ingresadas por factura en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
select *, sum(ingresosegresos.cantidad) from IngresosEgresos, products where IngresosEgresos.id_producto=11562 and DATE_FORMAT(IngresosEgresos.fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')>='2021-04-14' and DATE_FORMAT(IngresosEgresos.fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')<='2021-04-14' GROUP BY `IngresosEgresos`.`id_detalle`
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que haga sume de la cantidad ingresada en relación a su factura

Entonces hice lo siguiente:

```
select *, sum(ingresosegresos.cantidad) from IngresosEgresos, products
where IngresosEgresos.id_producto=11562 and
DATE_FORMAT(IngresosEgresos.fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')>='2021-04-14' and
DATE_FORMAT(IngresosEgresos.fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')<='2021-04-14' GROUP BY 
IngresosEgresos.numero_factura ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces necesito que me devuelve la suma del total de la cantidad ingresada por factura...

No se si me doy a entender o no soy muy bueno en BD, les agradecería bastante su ayuda.

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta quitando las mayusculas? Parece como si gritaras

Comment: En tus fotos no se ve el campo `sum(ingresosegresos.cantidad)`, debería estar al final de la tabla como ultima columna, ademas ¿porque seleccionas la tabla de  productos si no lo estas usando para filtro o para relacionarlo con algún campo? en dado caso necesitarías una sentencia JOIN